How debug flutter app from VS Code properly?
I am new on flutter. I am using vs code. Sometimes I see that the app is getting stack in a particular event or page. Then I restart debugging on same place it gets stacked again.
And then after trying many times, I just open same codebase into android studio and I run app from android studio into same emulator which one I use before with vs code. Suddenly I am seeing a red screen like following the error message, it gets easier for me to fix issues.
But question is why I cannot see that error red screen when I open the app from vs code? Instead, it just getting stacked.
If you have any idea please give me suggestions?

On VS Code I use following indicator button for starting the app.
VS Code Screnshot

I recommend you to debug you app using command
flutter run -v

This command give show you errors in terminal and on screen also
to

Hot reload use r
Hot restart use R
terminate use q
I hope this will help you.



have you also installed the 2 extensions for VSCode (Dart / Flutter)?
how do you start the debugging? Via F5 / green button in the debugging area or via the console?

lG Felix


Yes, I installed that extensions.
I update the question with new image. You can know how I start the app from vs code!

